# Missing whitespace in label text values?

Tags: api, openfda, json

As context for this question, look at the response for NDA211172 (inotersen) from the `label.json` endpoint: https://api.fda.gov/drug/label.json?search=openfda.application_number.exact:NDA211172

I have an internal tool for tracking content changes between versions of labels per application ID. This one just changed version from 4 to 5 and got a new SPL ID (`ec6ce482-951a-455f-aba3-f7cf8d42cd29`).

The diff for the change in label shows a bunch of places where whitespace has been removed and created many places where words are incorrectly concatenated together. For example, look at the `drug_interactions` field

`7 DRUG INTERACTIONS7.1 Antiplatelet Drugs or Anticoagulant MedicationsBecause of the risk`

This has 2 places where words are missing significant whitespace: `INTERACTIONS7.1` and `MedicationsBecause`

I'm guessing this is due to some data transformation process that isn't handling newline characters like `\n` and `\r` properly.

This is not a problem in older versions of JSON labels so I expect there must be some change over the past year that is incrementally introducing this bug in more and mover labels over time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you for bringing this to our attention. We have [created an issue](https://github.com/FDA/openfda/issues/141) in our GitHub repository to track resolution. We will post back on that link once the problem is remediated.

Comment: This is now fixed.

Comment: I can confirm that I'm seeing the fix. Thanks for the quick turn-around time, you've been very helpful.